# unique GET() method for link-file address for nodejs

Tags: node.js

```
var path=["file1","file2","file3"]

for (var tmp in path){
  app.get('/'+path[tmp], function(req, res){
    //var file = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/upload-folder/dramaticpenguin.MOV', 'binary');
    var pathfFile_tmp=__dirname+"/"+path[tmp]+".bin"
    console.log(pathfFile_tmp);
    var file = fs.readFileSync(pathfFile_tmp, 'binary');
    console.log(file);
    res.setHeader('Content-Length', file.length);
    res.write(file, 'binary');
    res.end();
  });
}
```

the nodeJS server generates a functionable unique link address .../file1, .../file2, .../file3 that works but all the links point out to the last same file of the array. function(req, res) is common for each get method and remains at the last "for"cycle value

How can I avoid having the same function for the get method?

Comment: For the most quick work around, just change your all `var` to `let`. For more information, search for `variable hoisting` and difference b/w `var` and `let`

Comment: thank you for reminding me that I have to be careful with the var and let! thanks... that actually solved my running code

Comment: this shows how much matters the declarations in js var vs let

Comment: see the explanations @ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sjyJBL5fkp8